# jQuery check all fields with return

Tags: jquery, forms, return

I've got this jQuery code to check fields in a checkout form. It works and does what it needs to, but it stops checking for fields whenever it hits the first false:

```
  $('#' + x + ' input.required-entry').each(function() {
      var item = $(this);

          if (item.val() === '' || item.is(':invalid')) {
            item.addClass('field-error');
            return isValid = false;
          } else {
            item.removeClass('field-error');
            return isValid = true;
          }

  });
```

Say I fill in 2 of the 10 fields and try to submit, this code only marks the 3th field as incorrect. The goal is to label all unfilled fields as incorrect. If I remove the `return isValid` line it does mark all the following fields invalid, but the form goes through anyway because `isValid` isn't changed.

Is there any way to run the code for all following fields after it hits the first `return isValid = false` ?

Comment: Replace the return statements with the setting of a flag, and have a single return statement at the end that returns a value based on said flag ...

Answer (score 0):

I'd introduce a variable outside the loop which you update if any are incorrect, then use the loop as is to update the classes.

```
 var areAnyIncorrect = false;
 $('#' + x + ' input.required-entry').each(function() {
      var item = $(this);

          if (item.val() === '' || item.is(':invalid')) {
            item.addClass('field-error');
            areAnyIncorrect = true
          } else {
            item.removeClass('field-error');
          }

  });
  return areAnyIncorrect;
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all items and and set the `isValid` flag against each item. This function will return all values with `isValid` flag.

```
function checkItems(){
var items= [];
$('#' + x + ' input.required-entry').each(function() {
 var item = $(this);
    var itemId = item.attr('id');
    var object = {
    ItemId:itemId,
    IsValid:true
    };
    if (item.val() === '' || item.is(':invalid')) {
    item.addClass('field-error');
    object.isValid=false;
    items.push(object);

    }
    else {
    item.removeClass('field-error');
    items.push(object);
    }           
});
return items;
}
```